# Economics.SE has entered Public beta

Tags: discussion

The **second attempt** to launch an **Economics.SE** site has [gone into public Beta.](https://economics.stackexchange.com/)
On-topic there are of course **Econometrics** also, so if you hit on an econometric question on Cross Validated that rests unanswered, you may consider flagging it for migration, or alert the OP about the existence of Economics.SE.
I will check older CV unanswered questions with the tag "econometrics", with the same intent.

If the site stays on, perhaps it will become a new source of cross-posting, but we will have to wait and see.

Comment: My suggestion about econometrics questions which relates to statistics and which are asked here, should remain on CV. Also, I don't believe it is a good idea to migrate old unanswered questions: the OP could be inactive. Better closing the question if it is unclear or off-topic.

Comment: @Glen_b Older content can be migrated manually (just copy-paste the text), being transformed in the process. But I have done the search, and found nothing in the unanswered queue here with the econometrics tag, that would be fit for Economics.SE.

Answer (score 6):

It does seem like economics merits its own SE site, so I wish it well.  However, deciding whether to migrate new questions will be tricky.  We have (but rarely) gotten questions that are rather purely about economics with little statistical content--those can clearly be migrated.  Econometric questions that have meaningful statistical content *could* be migrated, but I'm not sure I'd want to by default and there is some case to be made that we should defer to the OP's implied wishes in posting here for those questions that can be on-topic on two sites.  As with software and math questions, I suggest we focus on what the OP needs explained:  If the question is about econometrics, but the underlying confusion is really about the economics, we should migrate; If the question starts and stops with the econometrics, I would keep it here.  As for *old and unanswered* econometrics questions, be aware that after a short period of time (I don't know how long, it may be 30 days) threads are no longer migratable.

Comment: Your answer sounds like we disagree on something, while we don't: I did not propose "migration by default". I wrote about "alerting the OP" and let him decide. Econometrics are the child of Economics and Statistics, and so certainly some of the child's needs will be better served by the one parent, while others by the other.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, I was responding to the phrase before that ("flagging it for migration"), but I didn't mean to be argumentative. The main point I wanted to make in my answer was that the issue would be tricky to adjudicate. I recognize you have the best of intentions here & I trust your judgment.

Comment: (+1) As well as considering the OP's wishes, it'd be a shame to start removing areas of applied statistics from CV's remit (& where would it end?). Rather hope that the Economics SE helps bring more econometricians to CV.